# Python Pyqt Sync Sorting Between Two Tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I've been trying to find a solution or example to sync the column sorting of my `table1` with my `table2` , `table1` have associated values to `table2`, their row count is the same and only `table1` will be sorted but `table2` may contain some buttons. I have found an example [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/63276-Sync-sorting-of-a-QTableWidget-to-other-QTableWidget) but unfortunately it is in `C++` which I really tried to understand but I can't. How can I sort `table1` while keeping `table2`'s row in sync with `table1`? I am using `QTableWidget`.

```
____________    ______________
| table1   |    | table2      |
|----------|    |-------------|
|DDD       |    |data of DDD  |
|----------|    |-------------|
|AAAA      |    |data of AAAA |
|----------|    |-------------|
|CCCC      |    |data of CCCC |
|__________|    |_____________|
```

I am using two tables because I am using `table1` as a `frozen` column.
I can use a hidden column in `table2` where the value of this column can be used as an `id` or reference to re-sync `table2` but I would like to avoid that as it will be a very slow way of sorting.

Comment: You could explain yourself better, an example would make it clearer.

Comment: Are you using QtableWidget or QTableView?

Comment: I am using QTableWidget

Comment: I think I'm understanding you, you have 2 tables where each row of a QTableWidget has a correspondence with a row of the other QTableWidget, and you want that if one of the QTableWidgets is ordered it also reflects the same change in the others, am I in the right thing ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need

Comment: I think that using QTableView the solution would be simpler, could you use QTableView?

Comment: If `QTableView` can display widgets as `table2` may contain widgets, then yes.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use QTableViews with a model and a QSortFilterProxyModel, so when you order the QTableView you will be ordering the model, which will notify the other QTableView.

This solution saves resources since it orders only one element: the model.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)

        table1 = QtGui.QTableView()
        table1.setModel(proxy)
        table1.setSortingEnabled(True)

        table2 = QtGui.QTableView()
        table2.setModel(proxy)


        for i in range(100):
            for j, w in enumerate([QtGui.QLineEdit, QtGui.QPushButton, QtGui.QCheckBox]):
                text = "{}-{}".format(i,j)
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                if j == 0:
                    it.setText(text)

                model.setItem(i, j, it)

                ix = model.indexFromItem(it)
                widget = w(text)
                table2.setIndexWidget(proxy.mapFromSource(ix), widget)

        for i in range(1, proxy.columnCount()):
            table1.setColumnHidden(i, True)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        splitter = QtGui.QSplitter()
        splitter.addWidget(table1)
        splitter.addWidget(table2)
        lay.addWidget(splitter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been busy and I've just tried it, I am having trouble setting my widgets on the second table as the columns of `table2` is more than 20 columns with button only, I'll be posting my code

Comment: @JuanCarlosAsuncion 
Does my example meet what you require?

Comment: Yes It does, I think. but I'll mark this as an answer for now